# How to convert CIL to a LINQ Expression Tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees, cil, decompiling, linq-expressions

1. Has any work been done on the direct conversion of CIL to LINQ expression trees?  This would include class libraries, blogs, books, academic papers, etc.
2. What are the known mismatches between CIL and LINQ Expression API?  I have seen [a project](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/CSharp4Expressions/) that significantly extended the Expression API to support an almost complete mapping between C# and LINQ Expressions.  What work arounds would be suggested to accommodate any of these mismatches?
3. Is there something fundamentally wrong about converting directly from CIL to LINQ Expressions?  If so, why?

Comment: @SLaks, not exactly.  As I understand it, a decompiler would produce uncompiled code (e.g. C# as text) from the compiled code.  I'm interested in building a LINQ expression tree that can be used at runtime...  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You want a superset of a decompiler – a decompiler invoked at runtime that outputs expression trees rather than text.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, what should I do in order to make this a real question?

Comment: @SLaks, thanks, I understand what I was confused about ow

Comment: LINQ Expressions is just a small subset of CIL. Look at the CCI.

Comment: @leppie , http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: I started a project to do this a while back. I made some progress on it but it got put on the back-burner for a while and I've not picked it up since.

Comment: @smartcaveman: Yes, that one and the sister project.

Comment: You asked many questions in your post, some of which are too broad, vague, subjective or ambiguous to be answerable.  To be a real question, it needs to be a single question that's answerable with a single answer.  Read the [faq] for more guidance.  Also, much of your post is conceptual; some of your questions may be a better fit on http://programmers.stackexchange.com