# Build SQL Where query from delegate

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I'm working on a little helper for adding, editing and removing objects from a database, the add method is working right now and given an object of type t, it checks the properties, the values, and generates a SQL Query to insert the data into a table (it assumes the table name is the type from the object, but can also be set manually)

What I want to do now is a method

```
public bool Update<T>(T obj, Func<T, bool> predicate)
```

So given an T **obj**, and a lambda function **predicate**, if predicate is

```
(o => o.Id = 1)
```

I want to generate

```
WHERE Id = 1
```

I've seen some similar questions, and I think [expression trees](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx) might be a good starting point, but all I've seen is how to manually create an expression, not how to create an expression from a delegate.

Is there a way to generate that SQL from the delegate?

EDIT: I finally could do what I wanted, and I made a little post about that [here](http://gosukiwi.blogspot.com.ar/2012/10/converting-c-anonymous-functions-to-sql.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824201/how-to-convert-cil-to-a-linq-expression-tree

Comment: @SLaks: Not much happening there...

Comment: It looks like you're creating your own ORM. Doesn't any of the existing ones suit you?

Comment: I'm just adding utility insert update and delete functions, I'm working with an Acess database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use an expression directly:

```
public bool Update<T>(T obj, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
```

You would call this the same way:

```
Update(obj, o => o.Id = 1);
```

This will provide you the full expression tree, which you can then decipher and translate into your SQL.  The compiler will build the expression tree from a lambda, just like it does with the `Func<T,bool>` delegate.

Once you have the expression tree, in your case, you should be able to create an [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) to parse the tree, and [find all of the Where statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4515615/65358) to convert to your `WHERE Id = 1` result.

Comment: And how would I call the method, would I need an expression to call it or would a delegate work?

Comment: @gosukiwi You call it exactly the same way.  The lambda builds the expression tree for you.  Edited to show the method call.

Comment: Thanks! I now could do as I wanted :) I'll probably write something about it though, it was surprisingly easy and I couldn't find info on that specifically

Comment: @gosukiwi For a lot of information about this kind of thing, see [Matt Warren's series of articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx), including things like how to work with (closed over) local variables inside expression trees.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely impossible to create an expression tree from a delegate.

Instead, you need to change your method to take an expression tree.
The compiler will allow callers to pass a lambda expression as the parameter, which will compile to an expression tree.